# Restriction of sheaves on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-cohomology

Let $C$ be a scheme of pure dimension $1$. Let $C_1$ be a closed subscheme of $C$ of pure dimension $1$. Denote by $i:C_1 \hookrightarrow C$ a closed immersion. Given a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $C$, there is a natural morphism $\mathcal{F} \to i_*(i^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))$. Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_C$-module. Is it true that $H^0(\mathcal{F}) \to H^0(i_*(i^{-1}(\mathcal{F})))$ is surjective? If not, is there any additional condition we can impose on $C_1$ (for example $C\backslash C_1$ is affine) such that we get a positive answer to the question?

Comment: I am curious: where does this question come from?  If you told us more about where your questions come from, perhaps MO users could provide more support than just listing counterexamples.

Comment: @Starr: I am trying to understand better the concept of extending a section by zero. For instance when can I extend a section on $C_1$ to the whole of $C$.

Comment: The global sections of $i^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$ are "the same as" equivalence classes of sections of $\mathcal{F}$ on open neighborhoods of $C_1$ in $C$, where two sections are equivalent if their restrictions agree on some open neighborhood of $C_1$.  So your problem is roughly the same as the problem of extending a section on an open to a global section.  This is always possible for flasque sheaves, but rarely possible for coherent sheaves.

Answer (score 1):

There are counterexamples.  Let $C$ be a union of two copies, $C_1$ and $C_2$, of $\mathbb{P}^1$ intersecting transversally at a single ordinary node, $p$.  For definiteness, in $\mathbb{P}^2$ with homogeneous coordinates $[x,y,z]$, let $C$ be the zero scheme of $xy$, let $C_1$ be the zero scheme of $x$, let $C_2$ be the zero scheme of $y$, and let $p$ be $[0,0,1]$.  Let $q$ be a point on $C_2\setminus (C_1\cap C_2)$, e.g., $q$ could be $[1,0,0]$.  Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the ideal sheaf of $q$ as a closed subscheme of $C$.  In particular, on the open subscheme $U=C\setminus\{q\}$, $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_U$.  Thus the image of $1\in \mathcal{O}_U(U)$ gives a nonzero global section of $i^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$ on $C_1$, hence also of $i_*(i^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))$ on $C$.  On the other hand, $\mathcal{F}$ has only the zero global section.

The complement of $C_1$ in $C$ is affine, so that hypothesis is not sufficient to conclude surjectivity.

Comment: Dear Jason, will you excuse my curiosity if I ask you why you made this answer community wiki ?